# Flashing factory image - all data still present

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-image

I've just flashed my Nexus5 with Android 5.1 factory image using this how to:

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/11/05/how-to-flash-nexus-5-factory-images/

I've made a complete backup off all my data since I was sure I'll loose it.
Also the how to states:

> "*Flashing factory images wipes your phone completely clean, leaving
>   it at a factory, out-of-the-box state."

This also happened after flashing my Note 4 with Android 5 withe the rom downloaded from sammobile.com. (flashed via Odin)

So - why is all my data (photos, apps, calendar/contacts) still present after flashing the new rom?

Answer (score 0):

The apps and user data (everything that gets erased by factory reset) are contained within the */data* partition (in fact, "factory reset" simply formats the */data* partition). This partition is independent of other partitions. Android system is located on the */system* partition. That means that, as long you don't wipe your */data* partition, your apps and data will stay in the phone even when you change your Android version.

It is, however, recommended to wipe your */data* partition when moving from one Android version to another, due to incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

In that guide it says:

> *If you don’t want to wipe data, remove the “-w” in the second to last command.

Therefore if you removed the "-w" then your user data will not have be touched/wiped when flashing the factory image.